# Tag-it jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, multi-select, tag-it

I want to use https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it in my project. Unfortunately I could not find any option to restrict user to only enter values from predefiened ajax values.

Also I want to customize its suggestion menu and add image to it. I know how customize a jquery ui widget `_renderMenu()` function. What about tag-it?

Answer (score 0):

As tag-it is essentially turning a list into a fancy dropdown box, the restriction of what can be entered into the box is based upon the items that are available in the list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });
</script>
<ul id="myTags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>Tag1</li>
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to get the values from some other place (database, file, whatever), you'll have to make sure you load that data into the list, first, and then call tagit() after that has completed (you could do it in the [complete callback function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of an ajax request, for example).

Of course, that will (as far as I can tell - I haven't used tag-it) only restrict the options from the GUI perspective. You should still be checking the data server-side for sanity.

Comment: You can test 'Preloading Data in Markup' example in http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html . As you see this does not prevent user from entering new items.

Comment: I switched to Selectize.js its far better than tagit.